# Y-Axis Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i want to display a Stockchart with Highcharts. To fill the chart with content i receive a JSON data file which contains data like:

```
[["2013-10-14 02:30:07",18.62],
["2013-10-14 02:15:07",18.69],
["2013-10-14 02:00:07",18.81],
["2013-10-14 01:45:06",18.91]]
```

My Script looks like this:

```
$function() {
        $.getJSON('paht/to/data.json', function(data) {
            $('#Chart_Temp').highcharts('StockChart', {
                rangeSelector : {
                    selected : 1
                },

                series : [{
                    color: '#DF013A',
                    data : data,
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                             }
                         }]
            });
        });
    });
```

The Problem with that is, that the x-axis don't show the time properly. I had a look at the documentation and dateFormat - but i just can't get Highchart using the time properly. 
Does anybody can help me out? That would be awesome.

Comment: instead of date send the timestamp, set the xAxis type to 'datetime'.  hope this will work

Comment: Well, if i add 'datetime' to the xAxis, the graph won't show up. I converted my Time to the timestamp "1381734195" and so on...

Comment: use label formatter, then you can handle the timestamp as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a exapmle for datetime xAxis with timestamps,

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3yg8b/

Comment: Thank you. I updated this with my code - may you have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/BkaF4/1/ I replaced the $getJSON with three values in series -> data

Comment: timestamp should not be a string, it should be in milliseconds, and more over i gave an exapmle in highstock here is an example in highchart. http://jsfiddle.net/Ya5t6/ this will work fine

Comment: Well, now it works...but i don't know exactly why. My timestamps were wrong (i get them from a MySQL database and there i use the timestamp form) and i guess there were also some syntax issues. So, thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate that!